# Piping Identity Parameter

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm attempting to make mass changes to computer objects in AD, however the changes are coming from a text file, with the script below, i'm unable to pipe "samaccountname" to the -identity parameter for the subset of PCs i'm make changes to. It must be something really simple that i'm missing, however any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all!

```
 Get-QADComputer -searchroot "gwinet.net/DigiSign/DigiSign" |
 where {$_.computername -like "DS-*" -and $_.parentcontainer -eq "gwinet.net/DigiSign/DigiSign" -and $_.samaccountname -notlike "*$*"}|
 select samaccountname|
 get-content c:\digisignpcs.txt|ForEach-Object{
 Set-QADComputer  -SamAccountName $_.toupper()}
```

Comment: Tell us (post an example) what's the content of digisignpc.txt and exactly what are the changes that you want apply.

Comment: The change i want to make to all of the objects is to add '$' at the end of the samaccountname property in order to be able to bind the ad object to the physical machine when adding it to the domain. So the txt file has all of the machine names with a dollar sign at the end i.e 'DS-AGR-MOBI-W7$'